# TIF plot created from mirt object shows different values in summary?

Tags: r

I have created a mirt object with following code. However the plot  (see figure) seems to show different results than the summary?
(btw The ' originalparams' contains the a and d values from 35 likert scale items. Converting these into b paramters yields an error).

How can I solve this?

```
mod <- generate.mirt_object(originalparams, itemtype = "graded")
thetas <- fscores(mod, method = "EAP", full.scores.SE = TRUE)
plot(mod, type = 'info')


summary(thetas)
F1 minimum  -2.9 
F1 maximum -1.4
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share the data. The only data used here is the orginalparams object which is a dataframe with colnames |  a1  |  d1  |  d2  |  d3  | d4 | containing 35 rows. i.e.:     |  3  | -1.2 | -1.1| -0.1 | 0.7 |.  (the d values must be in ascending order of course). The issue is dat de plot and the summary show different results. I have reason to believe that the plot is showing the right results but that te summary is wrong i.e. doesn't make any sense